# How to do SVN merge from trunk to a branch within a range

Tags: svn, merge

Suppose I check out trunk and I am root of trunk directory in my local machine and I want to merge changes made to the trunk (range 62-65) to a branch.
I checked out trunk and did `svn up` and run this merge cmd.

```
svn merge -r 62-65 svn+ssh://url/to/branch
```

It run ok but the result was wrong.
I run svn diff see those changes and found out a log saying the range I specified was applied to the branch.

```
Merged /trunk/MyApp:r12-15
Merged /branch:r62-65
```

What I was trying to do is to take those changes from trunk which I am currently at in my locally machine within the range 62-65 and applying those changes to the branch I specified.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To merge a range of revisions from *trunk* onto a *branch* you need to have the *branch* checked out, not *trunk*.

From the root of your working copy do something like this:

```
svn sw url/to/branches/branch
svn merge -r 62:65 url/to/trunk
```

... then fix any merge conflicts, review and commit if you're happy.

Comment: And for newbie - # at first go to file system path - cd {{fs_path_destination_branch}}, # then run "svn sw {{url_path_destination_branch}}" with url by svn explorer, # then svn merge {{url_path_source_branch/trunk}} with url by svn explorer.

Answer (score 9):

```
1) use svn switch to go to branch
2) svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible "url_to_trunk"  (it will show eligible revisions)
3) svn merge --dry-run -r 74299:74493 "url_to_trunk" (dry run is used to see what will happen after marge i.e., if any conflict or not. here merged from rev 74299 to rev 74493)
4) svn merge -r 74299:74493 "url_to_trunk" (finally merge)
5) svn commit (if expected result, commit merged files to branch)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check out a working copy of your branch

   svn co url/to/branch
2. Enter the working copy root
3. Merge relevant changesets from trunk and resolve all conflicts

   svn merge - r 63:65 ^/trunk
4. Verify that everything was properly merged and commit the branch.

Comment: Aren't the revision numbers to be lowered by one for the first in range, such as:  -r 61:65 to get the changesets for revisions 62 to 65 properly merged?